# GNU make: proper dependencies and handling of deleted files for a code generator

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a code generator that can generate many files in one run, and can be told which files to update. It's executing *much* faster, if only a subset of the files needs to be updated. The goal is collecting the files to be updated with make, and provide the list to the generator. Here is a simplified example of what I have so far:

```
all : object

# Create a dummy config for this test
config:
    touch config

# Touch the dep if a file needs to be updated. Update is needed, if the file
# is missing or out of date (older than config). There are more of these lines.
dep1 sources : config
    touch dep1

# Here we collect which dependencies were touched and call the generator with
# the proper file list ($?). There are many dep<n> in the prerequisite list.
gen_ready : dep1
    echo $?
    touch sources
    touch gen_ready

# And finally compile
object : sources | gen_ready
    cat sources
    touch object
```

The code works perfectly when updating the inputs (config). However, when deleting a generated file and restarting make in multi threads, the following happens:
make -j

```
touch dep1
cat sources
cat: sources: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:47: object] Error 1
```

When starting the build again, it works:

```
touch dep1
echo dep1
dep1
touch sources
touch gen_ready
cat sources
touch object
```

I believe, the problem is that the rule for **dep1 sources** tells make, that the recipe will produce sources, and it does not. Sources is needed in that recipe, to trigger touching the dep, when the file is missing. The rule for gen_ready is not triggered, because when starting make, dep1 was not yet touched.
Interestingly, in single thread mode, or if dep1 and sources are a grouped target (&:), it works.
By adding sources as a prerequisite to the gen_ready rule, it's possible to force invoking the generator rule, but the $? dependency list won't be complete. The dep touched in the same run won't appear in the list, only at the next run. Somehow make should be forced to rescan the dependencies. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear to me. How do you know which files must be (re)generated? The missing files plus the existing files older than config? And is your main problem that you want to invoke your generator only once? Could you please separate the description of what you try to achieve from the description of what you tried?

Comment: In the second rule from the top, dep1 is touched if the configuration files (input to the generator) change.
in the 3rd rule we check which dep files were touched, and call the generator with those items. This works well in practice, except when a generated file is deleted, but the gen_ready and/or the dep files are not deleted. I'm looking for a solution for this. It works in simpler cases but I'm struggling with this 2-level rules...